# Linux swap file creation and management

Tags: swap

I want to increase my swap size to be able to have the hibernate option. First, I tried to add some swapfile. I followed

https://bogdancornianu.com/change-swap-size-in-ubuntu/

and typed this in my terminal:

```
sudo dd if=/dev/zero of=swapfile bs=1G count=16
```

I get:

```
16+0 records in
16+0 records out
17179869184 bytes (17 GB, 16 GiB) copied, 206.949 s, 83.0 MB/s
```

then, I followed the instructions:

```
sudo mkswap /swapfile
```

But I get this error:

```
mkswap: cannot open /swapfile: No such file or directory
```

Then, I decided to resize my swap partition instead of swapfile. So I want to delete them. (I didn't create any before so I assume I can delete them all?) 
I followed this:

https://askubuntu.com/questions/904628/default-17-04-swap-file-location

I tried:

```
$ cat /proc/swaps
$ grep swap /etc/fstab
```

But I get nothing from the first one. Output from the second one is:

```
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   
available
Mem:          11862        3498        1014         138        7349        
7907
Swap:             0           0           0
```

I also tried (after reboot):

```
swapon -s
```

and get

```
Filename                Type        Size    Used    Priority
/dev/sdb3                               partition   3905532 0   -2
```

I wonder that did I successfully create swapfiles? How do I delete them if I did?

Comment: Hello, our new contributor! Please read our guidelines, and maybe more important note: You should really really read properly what you are typing, there is no space for typos in Linux!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The first issue is that your first command created a file, `swapfile`, in your current directory, and that your subsequent command(s) were explicitly referencing `/swapfile`, a file called `swapfile` in the root directory.  If that was not your current working directory when you executed the first command, all of the subsequent commands would be referring to a file that is not there to operate upon.

If you got no output from `cat /proc/swaps`, that indicates that either your system does not have `procfs` running (unlikely), or that you currently have *no* active swap space configured.

The output you claim to get from `grep swap /etc/fstab` makes no sense whatsoever.  That looks like the output of `free -m` (incidentally confirming that you have no active swap configured), not the partial contents of the filesystem table.

Your post-reboot `swapon -s` (which as the manual states gives the same information as `cat /proc/swaps`) indicates that at some point prior to your reboot, someone executed `swapoff`.

Comment: Got it! I found the swapfile in ~/, since I didn't cd to any other directory. So can I just remove it with rm command? Thank you!

Comment: You can indeed, or you can `mv` it to where you intended it to be if you haven't already started over from the correct directory.

Answer (score 4):

You made a typo:

```
of=swapfile
```

should be

```
of=/swapfile
```

the guide creates the swap file in the root directory, whereas the command that you entered would have created a swap file in your current directory.

Answer (score 1):

Delete the swapfile(s) by

```
sudo swapoff -v /?/swapfile
```

where /? represents the directory where you inadvertently created an extra swapfile.

```
sudo nano /etc/fstab
```

allows you to edit fstab where you can delete any reference to /?/swapfile

```
sudo rm /?/swapfile
```

deletes the spurious swapfile.